# Is there a way to get the Business Account ID used to log into an app with Facebook Login for Business?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I have created an application that uses **Facebook Login for Business**.  The authentication flow gets an Authorization Code that is then exchanged for a *System User Access Token*(SUAT).

A successful login returns the following payload:

```json
{
    "authResponse": {
        "userID": null,
        "expiresIn": null,
        "code": "AQA..."
    },
    "status": "connected"
}
```

This is then exchanged for a System User Access Token that looks like this:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "access_token": "EAAT...",
        "token_type": "bearer"
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to automate our internal processes once a user logs into our app.  Since a single client can have multiple Business Managers, I need to know details like; the Business Account ID, User Name, email, etc to be able to identify exactly which account was used to login.

I have tried debugging the access token both with the Facebook Developer Console and the following endpoint: [https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token={token-to-inspect}&access_token={app-token-or-admin-token}](https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=%7Btoken-to-inspect%7D&access_token=%7Bapp-token-or-admin-token%7D)
This returns a payload like this:

```json
{
    "data": {
        "app_id": "1234567890123456",
        "type": "SYSTEM_USER",
        "application": "My App",
        "data_access_expires_at": 0,
        "expires_at": 0,
        "is_valid": true,
        "issued_at": 1234567890,
        "scopes": [
            "pages_show_list"
            "public_profile"
        ],
        "granular_scopes": [
            {
                "scope": "pages_show_list"
            }
        ],
        "user_id": "123456789012345678"
    }
}
```

The UserID returned is an App-Scoped User ID and is always mapped to the System User associated with our own Business Manager.  What we would like is the Business Manager Account ID for the client that just logged in.

Comment: Are you using the JS SDK or manual login flow?

Comment: I'm just looking into this now not found anything just yet

Answer (score 0):

To get information about business, adaccounts and pages that user selected during a login process you could make a get request using System User Access Token :

```
curl --request GET --url 'https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/me?fields=accounts{name,id,business},adaccounts{name,id,account_id}&access_token=<system-user-access-token>'
```

And the response would be something like this:

```
{
"accounts": {
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "My Page",
            "id": "111111111111111",
            "business": {
                "id": "111111111111111",
                "name": "My Business"
            }
        }
    ],
    "paging": {
        "cursors": {
            "before": "before",
            "after": "after"
        }
    }
},
"adaccounts": {
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "My Ads",
            "id": "act_1111111111111111",
            "account_id": "1111111111111111"
        }
    ],
    "paging": {
        "cursors": {
            "before": "before",
            "after": "after"
        }
    }
}
}
```